# Speeding up filtering of frames using Numba

Tags: python, numpy, numba

I have the following code where I am taking every pixel across multiple frames in a video and passing it through a low pass filter (essentially temporal filtering of every pixel values). I am then taking these filtered pixels and creating new frames in the `buf2` array.

```
import cv2, numpy as np
from scipy.signal import butter, lfilter, freqz
from numba import jit

# Filter requirements.
order = 1
fs = 30.0       # sample rate, Hz
cutoff = 0.3  # desired cutoff frequency of the filter, Hz

buf2 = np.empty((frameCount, frameHeight, frameWidth, 3), np.dtype('uint8'))

for j in range(rows_in_frame):
    for k in range(columns_in_frame):
        l = array_containing_all_frames[:, j, k, 1] #Only looking at green channel
        y = butter_lowpass_filter(l, cutoff, fs, order)
        buf2[:, j, k, 1] = y
```

This takes a long time to run depending on the size of the frame and number of frames. I wanted to speed it up as much as possible so I have been trying to apply Numba to this problem in the following:

```
@jit(nopython=True)
def butter_lowpass_filter(data, cutoff, fs, order=5):
    b, a = butter_lowpass(cutoff, fs, order=order)
    y = lfilter(b, a, data)
    return y
```

However, it just returns an error saying `TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend) Untyped global name 'lfilter': cannot determine Numba type of <class 'function'>`

I wanted to know how I should use Numba properly in my situation to speed up the whole process as much as possible.

Comment: The available libraries that can be used with numba jit in nopython is fairly limited (pretty much only to numpy arrays and certain python builtin libraries). So the scipy function lfilter is not supported by numba. You would either need to implement a similar function using numpy types or perhaps try with object mode compilation in numba, which may not give the speed results that you expect.
You can find more information on numba supported types [here](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/reference/numpysupported.html)